# Slug field RecursionError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, slug

In my Django project, I want to create slug field from the title.

For example:

```
title = Arduino UNO

slug = arduino-uno
```

And if the slug field exists into my DB then I want to append a digit

For example:

```
 arduino-uno2
```

Here is title to slug generator logic:

```
def create_slug(title):
    qs = IndividualProduct.objects.filter(slug=title)
    if qs.exists():
        title = title + str(qs.last().id) 
        create_slug(title)
    else:
        return title


def slug_generator_for_image_folder(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.slug == None:
        title = slugify(instance.title)
        instance.slug = create_slug(title)
        instance.save()
    else:
        pass



pre_save.connect(slug_generator_for_image_folder, sender=IndividualProduct)
```

But this code is exceeding maximum recursion limit if I want to add a digit.

If I make the change of the code from

```
if qs.exists():
    .....
else:
    return title
```

to

```
 if qs.exists():
    .....
 return title
```

Then it is working perfectly.

I have tried both the code into python shell and it is working perfectly.

I am not understanding why it is not working into my Django models.

Comment: Do you not understand why it returns `None` with the existing code but some other value with the change, or do you not understand why returning `None` causes infinite recursion?

Comment: why it causes infinite recursion?

Comment: Can you give us an edited traceback, or at least tell us whether it's just `create_slug` being called 998 times in a row or a more complicated call stack?

Comment: go to this link and see the create_slug function       https://github.com/mizan96/microcircuitry/blob/master/products_app/models.py